# 7-adic expansion of a rational number

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I know that every rational number has a unique 7-adic expansion, now I need help proving that $7/36=\sum\limits_{i=0}^nn7^n$ as a 7-adic integer. I tried using properties of this fraction, like adding it various times, but this didn´t seem to help. I don´t know what else to do. Any help would be great.

Comment: Should it be $7^{-n}$ in the sum?  Then we could use a variation of the geometric series $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum nx^n$

Comment: No,@AlainRemillard, ’cause that wouldn’t be $7$-adically convergent.

Comment: Actually, the expansion is unique only if your coefficients are in the range $0,\dots,p-1$. Your expansion has coefficients outside this range, which is fine.

Comment: What's your definition of $7$-adic integer? As a rational it should be clear that its $7$-adic valuation is nonnegative. As a power series it should be clear that it's a convergent series in the $7$-adic integers (which is a complete metric space). Lubin explained why the power series expansion holds, although you didn't explicitly ask why it did.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to multiply by $-6=1-7$ to get $7+7^2+7^3+7^4+\cdots=7/(1-7)$, which proves it.

For a more abstract argument, Alain Remillard’s idea in his comment is on the mark. When you expand $t/(t-1)^2$ as a series, you get $\sum_{n\ge1}nt^n$. But the evaluation $t\mapsto7$, as a function $\Bbb Z[[t]]\to\Bbb Z_7$ is continuous, ’cause you’re evaluating $t$ to something whose powers go to zero.

Comment: (Sidenote: one can prove the closed-form of this power-series without having to differentiate the geometric series, by noticing it is $(1+t+t^2+\cdots)(t+t^2+\cdots)$ if $|t|<1$.)